# JTable with updated values after a file search is performed

Tags: java, swing, file, jtable, file-search

I'm trying to create a program that searches a known file path for some files. If the search finds the file, I'd like for the program to update a `JTable` so that it removes that file from the table.

The point is for the table to display files that aren't yet in this certain folder.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XhPm.png]

edit: "Philly" and "L2" columns are server names. The rows are workstations that are on those servers. The two relate such that when the work has been completed on the workstations, the person who has completed that work takes a screen shot with "Snipping Tool", which is then saved as a .PNG file in a designated folder. The files are saved like... If server 1, workstation 1 was completed, it would be saved as "1-1 MyInitials.PNG" inside of the designated folder.

The idea of using an automatic TimerTask is a great idea, although I'm wholly unfamiliar with it.

Comment: And where is your code and your question?

Comment: My question is, how can I do this? What's the code (or a good hint) that will accomplish this? The picture I've included in my post shows the general form of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: My code is too long to include in a response. I'm not really sure how to include it other than to link my Git: https://github.com/sandalhathat/general-projects/blob/master/Clear.java

Comment: In order to assist you better I need to know a few things. In your JTable, what is **Philly** for and what is **L2** for? How do the two columns relate? Which column in the JTable holds the file name (if it's a file name at all)? Is there no file name extension to your files (ie: **.txt** or **.dat**, etc)? Can you give examples of file names? Please edit your post (if you can) rather than placing this info within a comment. To optionally do this sort of thing automatically a **TimerTask** can be used and providing an example of how this can be done would be best for you IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DefaultTableModel](https://www.thoughtco.com/defaulttablemodel-overview-2033890) of the JTable to search what is in table for a file name match.

- Iterate through the table rows and read the value within the cell
  column that contains the file name. You can use the the
  [DefaultTableModel#getRowCount()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getRowCount()) method and the
  [DefaultTableModel#getValueAt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getValueAt(int,%20int)) methods for this.
- Once you have found a match you would like to remove from table then
  you can use the [DefaultTableModel#removeRow()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#removeRow(int)) method.

A method to do this sort of thing **might look something like** this (**Not Tested**):

```
public void removeIfExist(JTable yourJTable, String fileName) {
    // Get Table Model
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) yourJTable.getModel();

    // Get Table Row Count
    int rowCount = dtm.getRowCount();

    // Assuming file names are in column 1 
    // and not in column 0.
    int fileNameColumn = 1; 

    // Iterate through each table row and get the String 
    // value for what is within the row cell of column 1.
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        // Grab the string value in column 1 of current row.
        String stringValue = dtm.getValueAt(i, fileNameColumn).toString();
        // Is the cell's String value the same as the file name?
        // If you want to ignore letter case for comparing then 
        // use equalsIgnoreCase() instead of equals().
        if (stringValue.equals(fileName)) {
            // Yes it is so remove the row from JTable.
            dtm.removeRow(i);
            // Found a match so no need to check 
            // further. Get out of loop.
            break;  
        }
        // No it's not so check the cell in next
        // table row (if there is one).
    }
}
```

You can of course modify this method to handle a list of file names instead of one file name at a time. Again, the code above is not tested and is just real quick off the top of my head but I think it gives you an idea of how it can be done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! I'll study and tinker around with this.

Comment: I found that the netbeans swing gui builder actually already creates the DefaultTableModel when you create a table in the builder. I can accomplish getting the code to search a file directory and return what I want it to, but I have trouble:
#1.) getting the "check" button to repeat the process, in the case of any files being added or deleted to the folder.
#2.) having the process of searching the folder after pressing the "check" button actually affect the contents of the table, without having to do it manually.

Any ideas?

Comment: In order to assist you better I need to know a few things. In your JTable, what is Philly for and what is L2 for? How do the two columns relate? Which column in the JTable holds the file name (if it's a file name at all)? Is there no file name extension to your files (ie: .txt or .dat, etc)? Can you give examples of file names? Please edit your post (if you can) rather than placing this info within a comment. To optionally do this sort of thing automatically a TimerTask can be used and providing an example of how this can be done would be best for you IMHO.

Comment: Ok I updated the first post, let me know what your thoughts are! :)

Comment: Thank you for the edit update. It cleared a lot of things up. I will have another answer for you shortly which will contain a runnable demo of how a TimerTask can be done for your use case. So..what L2 holds is considered as MyInitials in the file name?

Comment: Thanks again so much!

Comment: The demo application is too large to display in a post here. If you click on my name to the left you can get my email address. Send me a message and I will email the demo code to you.